# Error Loading Glass view statically

Tags: glass-mapper, presentation

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'xxx.models.Sitecore.IPage'.

I get above error if I statically load this like:

`@Html.Sitecore().ViewRendering("~/Views/xxx/Generic/PageIntro.cshtml")`

If I create a "View Rendering" item in Sitecore and load it from Presentation Details dynamically it works okay.

View I am trying to load "PageIntro" is a GlassView

Why is this?

Comment: Can you please provide more details on how the solution is set up. There are couple of questions like how is the Model generated (is it auto generated through the Glass Mapper), how are the controllers setup and any route config updates.

Comment: You can change your code and use `@Html.Partial("~/Views/xxx/Generic/PageIntro.cshtml", Model)` assuming that Model is the same what is defined in the containing page.

Comment: @Jammykam That also works as well :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A View Rendering must always declare a Model of type `RenderingModel` which is the default used by Sitecore and that's the only type that will be returned if you use `@Html.Sitecore().ViewRendering("")`.

My guess is that your View `~/Views/xxx/Generic/PageIntro.cshtml` defines a Glass Model as the model type being returned.

Instead you should be using a Controller Rendering.  To do that, I would recommend that you use `@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{Guid of Defined Controller Rendering In Sitecore}")

Then define in your controller rendering definition in Sitecore a Controller and Action that will be used to build that custom model used by your view.